# Digikam - How to view thumbnail icons in 22.04

Tags: themes, 22.04, digikam

Since installing Ubuntu 22.04 icons are missing on the thumbnails images in Digikam.  In particular, the mini icon top right of a globe to signify "this item has geolocation information" is missing though the tool tip can be made to display by mouse over the icon that does not display.  Digikam is 7.5.0 installed from synaptic.  The snap of Digikam 7.6.0 did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Installing breeze from synaptic solves this. Perhaps it should be addressed as a dependency in Ubuntu 22.04 onwards.

Answer (score 0):

"Since installing Ubuntu 22.04 icons are missing on the thumbnails images in Digikam"

You copied them from another hard drive - - yes?
This happens to me also.  the only fix I've found is remaining them.  Highlight the file,  hit F2, and have remove unhelpful part of the file name, or just give it another name. Often removing or replacing a single letter in the name does it.

Comment: Not sure if you mean file names.  That was not the issue for me.  

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=458968 

The forum ref above solved the bug ID = 458968
Everything is now good.  But Ubuntu dependencies may need to be fixed.